# How to insert data in the same table and row in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Good day everyone! I want to record the time in and time out of an employee using date time picker. Saving the time in is good, but the time out it will not save. I have to buttons labeled Time in and Time out. what I want to do is when I press the time out button I want to record the time of the said employee. I hope someone can help me, I am still searching in the internet but nothing seems to work. Thanks in advance guys!

My code looks like this.

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO timelogTB (Time_Out) select Time_Out from timelogTB WHERE EmpNo= '" & comboxEmpno.Text & "'" & _
            "VALUES (@Time_Out)"

                  'add parameters
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add(New SqlParameter("@Time_Out", dtpTime.Value.TimeOfDay))
        End With
```

Comment: Your sql statement makes no sense. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: It was inside a command button it will record the time using date time picker I want to insert it in the same row of an employee that has already time in.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant table DDL statement.

Comment: You cannot INSERT into an existing row - that is called an UPDATE

Answer (score 0):

Use `Update` because row for employee already exists in database and use `WHERE` condition to save out time in row of correct user.
**And use SqlParameters for all values you use in the query.**

```vb
cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE timelogTB SET Time_Out = @Time_Out WHERE EmpNo=@EmpNo"
Dim parameters As SqlParameter() =
{
    New SqlParameter With 
    { 
        .ParameterName = "@Time_Out",
        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
        .Value = dtpTime.Value.TimeOfDay
    },
    New SqlParameter With 
    { 
        .ParameterName = "@EmpNo",
        .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
        .Value = comboxEmpno.Text
    }
}

cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters)

' Execute query
```

And as Zohar Peled noticed, if `timelogTB` table contain input-output times for different days, then you need to add more `WHERE` condition for updating correct row.
For example you need update only row where `Time_Out` is null.

```
"UPDATE timelogTB SET Time_Out = @Time_Out WHERE EmpNo=@EmpNo AND Time_Out IS NULL"
```

Comment: This will update all records that belongs to this employee. The where clause is not good enough.

Comment: The time saved is in this format 15:21:41.3761497 how can I save it without the milliseconds?

Comment: You can truncate milliseconds from `dtpTime.Value` fro example like this: `date = new Date(dtpTime.Value.Ticks - (dtpTime.Value.Ticks Mod TimeSpan.TicksPerSecond))` or consider changing type of the database column to `SmallDateTime` but in this case seconds will be truncated as well.

Comment: The date is also saved. I want to save only the time because I have a separate column for date.

Comment: Use `TimeOfDay` of new "truncated" date.

Comment: Sir Fabio I use truncate milliseconds functions thank you very much!

Comment: Sir Fabio. My new question is how do I compute the total days worked and the time using the date time picker.

Comment: @AtanHokage04, "close" this question and create another one.